# export gcsfuse mount so a third client can access files in a storage bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-storage, gcsfuse

I mount a storage bucket to a local directory. `/share`
Then I try to make this directory - now populated with contents of the object store - available to another machine.
The goal is, that this other machine doesnt't have to use a gcsfuse-client itself but can rely on nfs or something similar.

I tried to expose the gcsfuse directory `/share` with nfs.
The nfs-share worked. But when I mounted the cloud storage bucket into the nfs share, the remote machine - the nfs-client - never saw the files from the object store.

So both parts of the chain work in seperate from each other:

- I can mount an object store to a local directory.
- I can export a directory per nfs to a second machine.

But I can NOT 'pass through' the contents of the object store to the second machine.

All that is happening inside a kubernetes cluster.

To rule out nfs from the equation, I used the sidecar-pattern, to expose the `/share` to a second container in the same pod.
Same result: the second container never sees the contents of the object store.

I don't know a lot about the (gcs)fuse-filesystem but people call it a 'user-space' file system.
Is that the reason, I cannot pass-through the contents of a gcsfuse mount to a second machine?

Edit: I tried multiple different options when mounting the object storage: here they are:

```sh
gcsfuse -o nonempty -o allow_other --implicit-dirs --gid 0 --uid 0 --file-mode 777 --dir-mode 777 video-storage-dev /share
```

```sh
gcsfuse -o nonempty -o allow_other video-storage-dev /share
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible solutions for this issue:

1. You might not have the `user_allow_other`config option enabled in the fuse config. To do this, make sure that in the file `/etc/fuse.conf`, you have the following line uncommented: `user_allow_other`, then try again.
2. If the above does not work, you might want to take a look at [this unix question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/102617/having-trouble-exporting-fuse-via-nfs), which addresses exporting FUSE via NFS. As a TL;DR, most Linux distros do not allow exporting a FUSE mounted fs via NFSv2 or NFSv3, so you will need to use NFSv4.